# How to add route parameter in SonataAdminBundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I have added the following code in my Admin class,

```
class ProductPriceAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        parent::configureRoutes($collection);
        $collection->add('price'); //I want to add a "id" as route parameter
    }
}
```

Here **price** is my custom function which I have declared in the controller as below,

```
class ProductPriceController extends Controller
{
    public function priceAction($id) //I want to use this variable
    {
         if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('LIST')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid();
        $formView = $datagrid->getForm()->createView();

        // set the theme for the current Admin Form
        $this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFilterTheme());

        return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('list'), array(
            'action'     => 'list',
            'form'       => $formView,
            'datagrid'   => $datagrid,
            'csrf_token' => $this->getCsrfToken('sonata.batch'),
        ));

    }
}
```

How to add route parameter when adding dynamic routing ?

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection->add('edit_price', 'price/{id}');
```

also you can view in Symfony\Component\Routing\Route\RouteCollection method add().